# Can we show data from database on web page using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to know about reading and showing data on web page using `bootstrap` if it is possible to show data using `bootstrap`. I studied about `bootstrap`, But did not found any `tag` or something to read data from database.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No.
Bootstrap Twitter is designed for the layout and presentation of your content.

However I do not feel this answer is helpful, other than to stop you looking further into Bootstrap for an answer.

What Technologies are you using for the web page and database, there are several choices you can make to access data that work well with Bootstraps presentation.
Knockout.js, AngularJS, Durandel(Aurelia) - the list goes on. Share your technology and people will be able to guide you better.

Comment: Can We do it using java script?

Comment: Yes - the best choice depends upon how your data is stored. What is your database?

Comment: @Varun What have you developed your website in? If plain html you will need some server side service to provide the data to the web page/javascript as JSON (for example).

Comment: It is single web page. Which is developed in `bootstrap`.

Comment: Depending upon your Web Host you need a PHP / RubyOnRails application to talk directly to Postgres. Is your Postgres server hosted on the same server as the web page. Take a look at the things I have mentioned an see if they help.

Comment: Web page and postgres are on same server.